# What's the ladder operator of Duffing Oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics

I know the ladder operator for harmonic oscillator can be obtained by factorization method, can the same method be applied to oscillators with potential $V(x)=x^{4}$ (the Duffing case) or higher degree like $V(x) = x^{2l}$ ? Or is there any result about their ladder operators?

**Further Notes:** We can surely get the integral kernel of ladder operator for an oscillator, which is $K(x,y) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\phi_{n-1}(x)\phi_{n}(y)$, this gives $C\phi_{n} = \int K(x,y)\phi_{n}(y)\mathrm{d}y = \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\phi_{n-1}$. Further examination of the kernel requires properties about the eigenfunctions, so perhaps some results on eigenfunctions will help.

Comment: not answering because I don't really know - but probably not.  This is a special thing that comes out of the harmonic oscillator. If it's not a harmonic oscillator, I don't expect to have a ladder operator (like the hydrogen atom doesn't have a ladder operator.)

Comment: @AndrewChristensen Thanks for commenting, and I've got some further notes about the question, do you have any thought about that?

Comment: yeah I'd agree - using this you can _always_ make a ladder operator (or in fact any mapping between states). But I think the problem is that this ladder operator won't be interesting or useful like it is in the harmonic oscillator - it won't just be x+ip (I think it's that?). It probably won't simplify in any way.

Comment: That's correct, thanks for thinking about my question@AndrewChristensen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harmonic oscillator is usually used to introduce creation and annihilation operators. In some cases these can be literally applied to more complex systems, representable as a system of oscillators, like electromagnetic field. However more general introduction of creation/annihilation operators is done more formally:
We start with a single-particle Hamiltonian:
$$
h\phi_n(x)=\epsilon_n\phi_n(x),
$$
Present the general wave function as
$$
\psi(x)=\sum_n c_n \phi_n(x), \psi^*(x)=\sum_n c_n^* \phi_n^*(x),
$$
and declare $c_n, c_n^*$ to be annihilation and creation operators $\hat{c}_n,\hat{c}_n^\dagger$, so that
$$
\hat{\psi}(x)=\sum_n \hat{c}_n \phi_n(x), \hat{\psi}^\dagger(x)=\sum_n \hat{c}_n^\dagger \phi_n^*(x),\\
\mathcal{H}=\int \text{d}x\hat{\psi}^\dagger(x) H\hat{\psi}(x)=\sum_n\epsilon_n\hat{c}_n^\dagger\hat{c}_n.
$$
This is called *second quantization*, and its mathematical foundations are explained in many texts, e.g.:
AGD: [Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Physics](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Methods_of_Quantum_Field_Theory_in_Stati.html?id=JYTCAgAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)
Fetter&Walecka: [Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486428273)
Mattuck:
[A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-Body Problem](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B00A73ALBI/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_tkin_p1_i0) (this one is easy and fun to read)

Now we could do the same trick for a Duffing oscillator or any one-particle Hamiltonian of your choice. And we will have creation/annihilation operators, which can be combined into raising/lowering operators - but we would not usually seek a closed form of these operators in terms of coordinates and differentials.

**TL;DR:**  They often start presenting second quantization with discussion of a harmonic oscillator, and it is confusing, because it prompts one trying to make generalizations along the wrong lines.